# Submitting data to Channel Images from outside EE

Tags: devdemon, channel-images

I run sports leagues, and want to have an interface where my photographers can upload images for a particular game in our system.  I've added some custom fields so that the photos can be tagged with the particular sport, the game ID in the database, and the team IDs of the two teams playing -- but they don't know any of this information, and the only way I'm able to do it is going to change all of the default values first (otherwise, clicking and typing all that data in is a big pain).

What obstacles would I hit if I try to create a form outside of EE that would submit to the same handler, and pass that information along in the form post?   I just want an interface where I can have my photographer click a game, and then drag/drop their photos, hit upload, and that's it.  On the back-end, I'd pass along the sport/game ID/team IDs to fill in the custom data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by looking at the Channel Form.
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/

It is designed for creating front end forms to input/edit channel entries without needing CP access.